# Problems benchmarking simple code with googlebenchmark

Tags: c++

I want to benchmark this simple C code:

```
float f(float x[], float y[]) {
  float p = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <64; i++)
    p += x[i] * y[i];
  return p;
}
```

My motivation is to try different compiler flags and also gcc and clang to see what difference it makes.

I found this [test framework](https://github.com/google/benchmark) and have been trying to get it to work.  Although I am completely new to C++, here is my best effort:

```
#include <benchmark.h>
#include <benchmark_api.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <random>

std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 gen(seed());

float f(float* x, float* y) {
  float p = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <64; i++) {
    p += x[i] * y[i];
  }
  return p;
}

void f_benchmark(benchmark::State& state) {
  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f((float*) state.range(0), (float*) state.range(1)));
  }
}

void args(benchmark::internal::Benchmark* b) {
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> rand(0, 100);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    float* x = new float[64];
    float* y = new float[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      x[i] = rand(gen);
      y[i] = rand(gen);

      printf("%f %f\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }

    b->Args({(int) x, (int) y});
  }
}

BENCHMARK(f_benchmark)->Apply(args);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

To compile it I do:

> g++ -Ofast -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp -Ibenchmark/include/benchmark/
>   -Lbenchmark/src/ -o test -lbenchmark -lpthread

This gives me :

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void f_benchmark(benchmark::State&)’:
test.cpp:20:54: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f((float*) state.range(0), (float*) state.range(1)));
[...]                                                                            
test.cpp: In function ‘void args(benchmark::internal::Benchmark*)’:
test.cpp:38:20: error: cast from ‘float*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
     b->Args({(int) x, (int) y});
                    ^
[...]
```

> How can I get rid of those warnings and in general, am I doing this
>   right?

Comment: Why all the casts? On a 64-bit build `int` would be 4 bytes and `float*` 8 bytes, so can't be converted at all. Not to mention the language's aliasing rules.

Comment: @BoPersson They may be mistakes (I am completely new to C++). Which ones do you think I can eliminate?

Comment: If I get rid of the casts to int so that I have " b->Args({ x,  y});" then when I run the code I get "benchmark/src/benchmark_register.cc:331: Args: Check `ArgsCnt() == -1 || ArgsCnt() == static_cast<int>(args.size())' failed. 
Aborted (core dumped)
"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code casts a `float*` to `int` and back to a `float*` - this can cause problems, because `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float*)` are not guaranteed to be identical (i.e. on x86-64 `int` is 32bit, while `float*` is 64bit!).
The reason why you run into this issue, is probably because `Args()` supports only `int` arguments (they're supposed to be used as index for a family of benchmarks, not as actual function arguments in your function). To use parameters of a different type you could:

**A. use global variables to store the pre-calculated random array**
i.e.

```
#include <benchmark.h>
#include <benchmark_api.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <random>

std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 gen(seed());

float x[64*10], y[64*10];

float f(float* x, float* y) {
  float p = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <64; i++) {
    p += x[i] * y[i];
  }
  return p;
}

void f_benchmark(benchmark::State& state) {
  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f(&x[state.range(0)*64], &y[state.range(0)*64]));
  }
}

void args(benchmark::internal::Benchmark* b) {
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> rand(0, 100);
  for (int i = 0; i < 64*10; i++) {
    x[i] = rand(gen);
    y[i] = rand(gen);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    b->Arg({ i });
}
BENCHMARK(f_benchmark)->Apply(args);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

**B. calculate the random numbers as part of the benchmark function** (choose this approach if, you really require different random values for each iteration - the timing needs to be paused / resumed accordingly to not include the time for the random generation/memory allocation in the benchmark)
i.e.

```
#include <benchmark.h>
#include <benchmark_api.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>

std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 gen(seed());

float f(float* x, float* y) {
  float p = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <64; i++) {
    p += x[i] * y[i];
  }
  return p;
}

void f_benchmark(benchmark::State& state) {
  state.PauseTiming();
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> rand(0, 100);
  float* x = new float[64];
  float* y = new float[64];
  while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      x[i] = rand(gen);
      y[i] = rand(gen);
    }
    state.ResumeTiming();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f(x, y));
    state.PauseTiming();
  }
  delete[] x;
  delete[] y;
}


BENCHMARK(f_benchmark)->Apply([](benchmark::internal::Benchmark* b){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    b->Arg({ i });
});

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Side note: Also take care about the the leaking memory in your `for` loop - you should call the `delete[]` operator once for every `new[]` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.